# install4j installs old/strange vmoptions

Tags: install4j

My vmoptions used to specify `-Xmx300m` but later [we updated it to `-Xmx512m`](https://github.com/FAForever/downlords-faf-client/commit/4914a06f1c1c524a3a85f098e196e53757e3f854).

My install4j configuration now contains:

```
<vmOptionsFile mode="content" overwriteMode="5" fileMode="644">
  <content># Enter one VM parameter per line

# Adjust maximum memory usage to 512MiB
-Xmx512m</content>
</vmOptionsFile>
```

Now, even if I manually uninstall the previous version and whatch the vmoptions file being deleted, installing the version I just built with the install4j file above gives me this vmoptions file:

```
# Enter one VM parameter per line

# Adjust maximum memory usage to 512MiB
-Xmx300m
```

Notice how the comment says **512MiB** while the parameter specifies **300m**.
This does *not* happen if I use the same installer within a fresh Windows VM.

I have not the slightest clue how this can happen. Any idea?

Comment: Do you maybe have a "Add VM options" action in your project for the -Xmx value? Such an action would replace an existing -Xmx entry in the vmoptions file.

Comment: No, there is no -Xmx specified anywhere except for vmOptionsFile. The whole install4j file can be seen at https://github.com/FAForever/downlords-faf-client/blob/b819997b2c4964ae6e6801d5d2eecd232bca5688/downlords-faf-client.install4j

Comment: Sorry but I have absolutely no idea how this could happen. Try to pause after the "Install files" action and check if the installed file has the expected content right after the installation.

Comment: Alright, I narrowed down the problem; it's **not** install4j that behaves strangely but PSPad editor. It somehow opens a file from a parallel universe (read: File System). I've never seen this before and I have no explanation, check this video: https://youtu.be/E8GgAnI82DI

Comment: Turns out, for some reason, PSPad was looking into `%LOCALAPPDATA%/VirtualStore` explaining this strange behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the update, very interesting.